# Facebook Redirect URI configuration for app that uses webhooks only

Tags: facebook-graph-api, redirect, restfb, facebook-webhooks

I have created an app that just wants Users to subscribe for User_events and manage_pages WebHooks subscriptions. As a developer I am able to test the WebHooks at my callback url where I am handling all my graph api calls and retrieving additional information using restfb.

I am confused on having a redirect uri, when I want users to authorize the app. Basically my understanding so far is that I need to make my app public and submit for review in order for others to see. Is redirect uri mandatory for my app? my app wont need users to visit my website or login to any of my callback urls. Only information I need when the user subscribe(or authorize) my app is their uid and pages they are giving me the permission to.

Please note I started reading about facebook webhooks and app development very recently (a week). Any suggestions would be great help.

Comment: If you want users to grant your app permissions, they must log in to your app to do so. And the redirect_uri is part of the web login flow.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe ! but does my redirect_uri needs to have UI elements in it or just needs to handle the GET and POST ? Is there a good article to overview of what might be the flow of calls? Facebook documentation is giving me a hard time.